# Remove null value from json and return it as json not json string in c#?

Tags: c#, json, api

I tried to remove null values from json. I used **[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]** and serialized the json to remove null values. It is working. But I need the output as JSON object, not JSON string.

Here I am serializing the **chatbotclass** for removing null values.
When I Serialize the object it is returning the result as string.
Is there any other ways available to remove null values without serializing.

```
    List<elements> elementList = new List<elements>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < articleList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        List<buttons> buttonList = new List<buttons>();
                        btnclass = new buttons();
                        btnclass.type = "web_url";
                        btnclass.url = Convert.ToString(Utility.GetAppsettingValue("MMUrl")) + articleList[i].Url;
                        btnclass.title = "Read this story";
                        buttonList.Add(btnclass);
                        eleclass = new elements();
                        eleclass.buttons = buttonList;
                        eleclass.title = articleList[i].HeadLine;
                        eleclass.image_url = articleList[i].ImageLink + "_SECVPF.gif";
                        eleclass.subtitle = articleList[i].Abstract;
                        elementList.Add(eleclass);
                    }
                    payldclass.elements = elementList;
                    payldclass.template_type = "generic";
                    atchmntclass.payload = payldclass;
                    atchmntclass.type = "template";
                    msgclass.attachement = atchmntclass;
                    List<messages> messageList = new List<messages>();
                    messageList.Add(msgclass);
                    chatbotclass.messages = messageList;
                    jsonstring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chatbotclass, Formatting.None);
                    return Json(jsonstring);
```

And also I tried Deserializing object. When Deserialize the string using **ChatbotMdl** it adds a null value to the missing fields.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                    };
var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatbotMdl>(jsonstring, settings);
```

Output I am getting:

```
"{\"messages\":[{\"attachement\":{\"type\":\"template\",\"payload\":{\"template_type\":\"generic\",\"elements\":[{\"title\":\"உத்தரபிரதேசத்தில் பள்ளத்தில் டிராக்டர் கவிழ்ந்து 4 பேர் பலி\",\"image_url\":\"https://img.maalaimalar.com/Articles/2018/Feb/201802050158532561_Four-Dies-As-Tractortrolly-Falls-From-Bridge_SECVPF.gif\",\"subtitle\":\"உத்தரபிரதேசத்தில் பள்ளத்தில் டிராக்டர் கவிழ்ந்த விபத்தில் டிராக்டரில் பயணம் செய்த 4 பேர் சம்பவ இடத்திலேயே உடல் நசுங்கி பரிதாபமாக உயிர் இழந்தனர்.\",\"buttons\":[{\"type\":\"web_url\",\"title\":\"Read this story\",\"url\":\"https://www.maalaimalar.com/News/TopNews/2018/02/05015853/1144022/Four-Dies-As-Tractortrolly-Falls-From-Bridge.vpf\"}]}]}}}]}"
```

Output I need:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "attachement": {
        "type": "template",
        "payload": {
          "template_type": "generic",
          "elements": [
            {
              "title": "உத்தரபிரதேசத்தில் பள்ளத்தில் டிராக்டர் கவிழ்ந்து 4 பேர் பலி",
              "image_url": "https://img.maalaimalar.com/Articles/2018/Feb/201802050158532561_Four-Dies-As-Tractortrolly-Falls-From-Bridge_SECVPF.gif",
              "subtitle": "உத்தரபிரதேசத்தில் பள்ளத்தில் டிராக்டர் கவிழ்ந்த விபத்தில் டிராக்டரில் பயணம் செய்த 4 பேர் சம்பவ இடத்திலேயே உடல் நசுங்கி பரிதாபமாக உயிர் இழந்தனர்.",
              "buttons": [
                {
                  "type": "web_url",
                  "title": "Read this story",
                  "url": "https://www.maalaimalar.com/News/TopNews/2018/02/05015853/1144022/Four-Dies-As-Tractortrolly-Falls-From-Bridge.vpf"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JObject.Parse(jsonString);` parses string to a JObject, so if you return it from your controller, it will be an object, not a string.

You can change this
`var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatbotMdl>(jsonstring, settings);` to this `dynamic jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);`. Because deserializing to ChatbotMdl gives you all the properties, obviously, even if they are null.

But if you have globally set `NullValueHandling` to `Ignore`, you should return `Json(chatbotclass);` and it should be ok. The framework will take care of it, you don't need to serialize it yourself.

Comment: When I return JObject.Parse(jsonString) I am getting "Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue. "exception

Comment: Return Json(JObject.Parse(jsonString))

Comment: Yes, this is what I returned. And one more thing when I change "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChatbotMdl>(jsonstring, settings);"  to "dynamic jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring, settings);" ,I cant able to pass settings.

Comment: Don't pass settings then. 
What project is this? Web Api2?

Comment: I am getting an error "cannot convert from Newtonsoft.Json.JsonserializerSettings to 'System.Type'"

Comment: What's the exact environment? .Net Core or Framework? And what version

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question by changing the return type of the method to HttpResponseMessage.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage getNewsList(string topic, string district, string type,string count)
 {    
    jsonstring = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chatbotclass, Formatting.None);                           
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonstring))
    {
       var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
       response.Content = new StringContent(jsonstring, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       return response;
    }
       throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);    
}
```